# Difference between use of a controller factory and NinjectHttpApplication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, ninject-2

Using Ninject 2 MVC 3. Correct me if i am wrong but ive seen two way of using Ninject in an MVC 3 application. We can use a new controller factory which is like ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory()); or using NinjectHttpApplication and then configure the kernel.

I was wondering what difference between use of a controller factory and NinjectHttpApplication to configure the binding for DI?

And what are the best place to setup DI ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NinjectHttpApplication calls ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory()) internally.

But additionally it sets up various bindings and provides many new features. In other words it's less work and adds new features. Best you read my blog post about the MVC3 extension. http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/

Comment: Nice blog post! So your saying NinjectHttpApplication is the way to go ? Also where are the best place to put NinjectModules ? Thanks.

Comment: I'd go with NinjectHttpApplication. I'd put the modules aside of the services and let ninject discover them by loading the assembly instead of the modules itself. But every one has its own preferencies regarding where to put modules and how many modules to use.